# Cannot open include file error but able to locate file

Tags: c++, c, compilation, compiler-errors

I'm getting the following error :

```
"fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file"
```

for one of my header files being **#included** in **stdafx.h**. I have set the include and library paths in the project dependencies, Tried to include them in additional include section. On top of that when I right click the

```
    #include <BCGCBProInc.h>
```

it is able to open the file and show it to me. So it can find and open the file but instead gives me the error. I am using VS2012 on Windows 7 and the header is in a different location then the project.

What am I doing wrong / not doing right?

Comment: Which compiler/platform?

Comment: @Sean: I am using VS2012 so whatever C++ MFC compiler that uses

Jonathan: I don't understand what your saying

Comment: It could also be a path problem. I mean the OP could include some other header that is not part of the system include paths.

Comment: @Katianie What file are you trying to include?

Comment: #include <BCGCBProInc.h> it is in a diffrent location then the project but that dosent matter because I have set the path in the dependencies in the project include and lib section

Comment: Did you set the path for the current configuration. I mean Relase, Debug ... configs all have separate paths unless you apply the change to all.

Comment: @drescherjm The Configuration is set to Active(Debug) and Platform Active(Win32) and I am compiling in Debug so that should be good.

Comment: Look at your actual compilation command and verify it is indeed using include directories it should be using.

Comment: That is not what n.m. wanted you to do. Look at the full command line of the compilation command in your project settings.

Comment: I would also verify that BCGCBProInc.h exists in the directory that you added by browsing to that folder in explorer.

Comment: Did you create this project on the same machine that you're working on it now?  If not, verify that the path is relative to your project, not the absolute path on a different machine.

Comment: @drescherjm It does exist and also i can right click it in VS and it takes me to it and opens it. Also I don't know how to "look at the full command line of the compilation command"

Comment: That's not the command, that's the log. The command can be seen in one of the tabs of the project properties (I think it's c++/command line tab).

Comment: @uberwulu the project already existed and I am working on it on one computer and the libraries/includes are on this computer.

Comment: @n.m. Ok I'm looking at the command and it does seems to mention BCGCBPros include and lib directories

Comment: What I meant was to ensure that the paths in your project settings are relative to the project (such as `$(SolutionDir)includes`) and not absolute paths that came from the computer it was created on (such as `D:\Development\MyProject\blahblah\includes`)

Comment: Did you try this include directly inside of a cpp that is in your project to take PCH out of the picture (although I doubt PCH is causing this)?

Comment: @uberwulu they are absolute paths but 1. I dont know how to specify a relitive path for them and 2. The files and everything are on this computer so i wouldent think it would matter. Also the files I am including are in a diffrent directory/folder then the project itself

Comment: To make them relative to the project, use `$(ProjectDir)` followed by the rest of the path: `$(ProjectDir)stuff/includes` for example, or `$(ProjectDir)../includes` to go up a level.  To make them relative to the solution, use `$(SolutionDir)`

Comment: These files are in C:Program Files(x86)\BCGSoft\ ... and my project is not

Comment: Did you specify that as the path to the includes and libs, and if so, is that path identical on both machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do to get it to compile was change

```
    #include "BCGCBProInc.h"
```

to this

```
    #include "C:\Program Files (x86)\BCGSoft\BCGControlBar Professional Evaluation\BCGCBPro\BCGCBProInc.h"
```

I'm not sure why because I included the path in the VC++ Directories. When I browse for the path it changes (x86) to %29x86%29 which is what I thoght was screwing it up but that is not the case because I manually changed it back to (x86).

My plan is when I eventually get what i need to get done, I will bring the libs and includes into the project locally and make the paths relative

Comment: `%28x86%29` shouldn't be a problem for VC.

Comment: I made mine the answer because this worked to get it to compile. The answers above are very useful and are important in trying to to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

1.

```
#include <BCGCBProInc.h>
```

is not the same as

2.

```
#include "BCGCBProInc.h"
```

Different search pathes apply to both variants of including a file.

The pathes looked up when using variant 1. are those defined as default search pathes like

- `/usr/include` for IXish systems
- `$(VCInstallDir)include` also called VC++ Directories for VC

The pathes used when using 2. are those added via the option `-I` (`/I` for VC).

Comment: I try to always do that but Visual Studio does not seem to care. At least up to VS2012.

Comment: To always do what? @drescherjm

Comment: Use #include<> when I mean system includes and #include "" when I mean project includes.

Comment: For completeness, `#include "..."` is required to fall back on the same search as `#include <...>` if its additional lookup paths don't find the header.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, right-click your project and choose Properties.  Select the VC++ Directories option in the left pane, and then look at the Include Directories and Library Directories in the right pane.  Make sure they are using relative paths and not absolute paths.  If they must be absolute paths, then every machine you run this project on will have to have the exact same path.  Absolute paths look like this:

```
D:/Development/MyProject/includes
```

Relative paths can be done using $(ProjectDir) to make it relative to the project, or $(SolutionDir) to make it relative to the solution (if different from project), and would look something like this:

```
$(ProjectDir)../includes
```

or

```
$(SolutionDir)includes
```

Comment: Yea that's what I will eventually do but for now I don't want to copy all of the .h files and libs to the project folder until I actually have what I want to do working.

Comment: Fair enough.  It seems like there might have been a mismatch between the path on the machine it was created on and the path on your machine.  In either case, your plan of moving the needed files to a local directory with relative paths should resolve it.